# Actionscript ExternalInterface call not reaching javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here since I'm completely new to Flash programming, but my Actionscript is not able to reach my javascript.

AS3.  I created a new .fla, and set the document class to Test.

```
package { 
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Test extends MovieClip{
    Test(){
        ExternalInterface.call("test");
    }
  }
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    embed();
});
function test(){
    alert("hi");
}
function embed(){
    swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf","test","642","410","11.7.0");
}
```

It correctly embeds the object but the test alert never goes off.  I'm running it both from a trusted folder and from a locally hosted web server.  In debug mode, it properly makes the call and ExternalInterface.available is true, so it appears as if the call should be made.  Any idea why it would not go off?

Comment: How you are testing this? Are you running your html from your local drive?

Comment: Is this your class? Are you actually able to compile it? It should throw you an error, you are missing the function keyword.

Comment: I am running the HTML from my localhost as well as the file directly.

This is my class, it does not throw any errors.

Changing to 
    public function Test():void
fixed the issue though, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try giving your embedded swf an id, replace your embed() with:

```
function embed(){
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};
    var attributes = {
      id: "test",
      name: "test"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf","test","642","410","11.7.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
}
```